# Create DOCX file with support for RTL (hebrew, arabic) using C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml-sdk, xceed, aspose.words

In the last several weeks i have figured that DOCX (XCEED) component does not support Hebrew really good, if i write something in Hebrew (Or Arabic) and need dot or colon at the end of the line, they appear at the beginning.

I'm still waiting for the developer to answer me but meanwhile i have look at all the options out there:

- Aspose (Way pricey and seems only to work as html to docx)
- OpenXML (Very hard to work and couldn't find the right example for me)
- HtmlToOpenXML (doesn't have RTL support and support on github is slow)
- OpenXML PowerTools (only do DOCX TO HTML)
- And several more

please - i you out there have a solution, that can work with images, table and many other basic stuff

i need your help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your inquiry. Aspose.Words supports wide range of document formats; it is not limited to Html and Docx. See the documentation to learn what formats are supported:
https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Product+Overview

Aspose.Words can be used as for conversion document between various formats as well as for creating documents from scratch using it’s rich API or using reporting features. You can also easily format text or whole paragraph as right-to-left
https://apireference.aspose.com/net/words/aspose.words/font/properties/bidi
https://apireference.aspose.com/net/words/aspose.words/paragraphformat/properties/bidi
The same options can be applied to Section or Table
https://apireference.aspose.com/net/words/aspose.words/pagesetup/properties/bidi
https://apireference.aspose.com/net/words/aspose.words.tables/table/properties/bidi
If you have further question, please do not hesitate to ask here or in Aspose.Words support forum.

Comment: Hi Alexey, i need to make a document from scratch and to stream it to the users as download without saving to the disk. do you have this option as well?

Comment: Sure, you can save the created document to stream and send it to the clients browser  without saving to the disk. https://apireference.aspose.com/net/words/aspose.words.document/save/methods/5 Please let me know if you need more help, I will be glad to assist you.